# Changing a minisign password

Tags: passwords, private-key

I have a minisign key that I want to change the password for.

The manpage doesn't mention anything about changing a password, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, [this is not possible](https://github.com/jedisct1/minisign/issues/75).

> This is not implemented in this command-line tool yet, but this is not a design limitation.